# Remove non numeric characters from a list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Amount = [USD $35 m, CAD $ 45 Millon, AED 25Mil ]
```

I am looking for an output:

```
Amount = [35,45,25]
```

I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Will there be only one number in each element ? You need to look into regex for this -

Comment: Are the original values in the amount list strings? Such as "Amount = ["USD $35 m", "CAD $ 45 Millon", "AED 25Mil"]

Comment: any values like `AED 250.50Mil` ?

Comment: ```nums = list("1234567890") {newline here}
Amount = [int("".join([j for j in i if j in nums])) for i in Amount]```

Comment: @Cheesebellies no need of function ``list``, a string behave like a list for ``in`` operator

Comment: Yep i saw that @Vincent Benet. And here I was thinking I was the only person who was going to use list comprehension.

Comment: thank you for your responses, yes there are values like 2.5 and 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex to achieve what you want :

```
import re

amount = ['USD $35 m', 'CAD $ 45 Millon', 'AED 25Mil' ]

print([re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', a) for a in amount])
```

This one takes floating point number in consideration, if not change it with this one :

```
re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', a)
```

Answer (score 2):

For:

```
Amount = ["USD $35 m", "CAD $ 45 Millon", "AED 25Mil"]
```

You can do this:

```
print([int("".join([ch for ch in el if ch in "0123456789"])) for el in Amount])
```

or

```
print([int("".join([ch for ch in el if ch.isdigit()])) for el in Amount])
```

Output:

```
[35, 45, 25]
```

IMPORTANT: If you have float values please use regex solution! This is NOT working for such element:

```
"Value 2.5 M€" >> 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amount = ["$36", "Test", 46, "26€"]
output = []

for x in amount:
    number = ""
    for char in [*str(x)]:
        if char.isnumeric():
            number += str(char)
    if number != '':
        output.append(int(number))

print(output)
```

Output will be: [36, 46, 26]

You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the values in the amount list are strings you can do like this:

```
amount = ['USD $35 m', 'CAD $ 45 Millon', 'AED 25Mil' ]
result = []
for i in amount:
    num = ''
    for j in i:
        if j.isnumeric():
            num = num + j
    result.append(num)
print(result)  # ['35', '45', '25']
```

You can also make it a function. Like this:

```
amount = ['USD $35 m', 'CAD $ 45 Millon', 'AED 25Mil' ]

def get_nums(amount_list):
    result = []
    for i in amount_list:
        num = ''
        for j in i:
            if j.isnumeric():
                num = num + j
        result.append(num)
    return result
    
print(get_nums(amount))  # ['35', '45', '25']
```

• See [this link](https://datagy.io/python-isdigit/) to more information about `isdigit()`, `isnumeric()`, and `isdecimal()` in python. It maybe be useful to your project.

Answer (score -1):

```
amount = ['USD $35 m', 'CAD $ 45 Millon', 'AED 25Mil']
output = []
for element in amount:
     curr = ''
     for char in element:
         if char.isdigit():
             curr += char
     output.append(curr)
output = [int(str_num) for str_num in output]
print(output)
```